# .htaccess preserve url on rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, web

I am redirecting a domain to a sub folder with the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/$1 [L]
```

however if I visit domain.net/folderinsidethatsub

the url is rewritten to

```
domain/net/subfolder/folderinsidethatsub
```

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because mod_dir redirects any request for a directory without a trailing slash to the same URL but with a trailing slash. There's a VERY GOOD REASON for this because it prevents the contents of the folder from being exposed (even if you have an index file). The only way to keep mod_dir from doing this is to turn off the `DirectorySlash` directive, however, you'll need mod_rewrite rules to add the trailing slash manually, otherwise people will be able to expose the contents of your directories. Add this above the rules that you already have:

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much you just saved me a lot of headache.